# Python3 script to get status of deluge

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I want to make a python script that every 30 minutes checks the status of a torrent on my RPI (where deluge is up and running) and if completed sends an email. I know how to make a timer, loop and email, but I don't know about deluge. I've read this: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/deluge/latest/deluge.pdf.

I know I need to import deluge and start with `get_session_state()` and get it to string, but it doesn't work.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "torrents_status.py", line 3, in <module>
    get_session_state()
    NameError: name 'get_session_state' is not defined
```

Comment: "It does not work" is not a good starting point for us to help. WHAT does not work? What's the error? What have you tried? Where's your code?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torrents_status.py", line 3, in <module>
    get_session_state()
NameError: name 'get_session_state' is not defined
That's the error

Answer (score 0):

If you are just doing `import deluge`,  you have to use the full module name for the methods.

```
deluge.get_session_state()
```

However, I'm imagining there is some connection object to the session that you should actually be calling that method on. I don't want to read through that 300 page manual, though, to find the correct module you should import.

---

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
from deluge import get_session_state
```

Then call

```
get_session_state()
```

Once again, you'll need to use the correct module name instead of `deluge`.

Comment: Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import delluge
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named delluge
>>> import deluge
>>> deluge.get_session_state()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_session_state'
>>> deluge.get_session_state()

Comment: from deluge import get_session_state
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name get_session_state

Comment: Did not not read my statement where you need to import the **correct** module? You have the PDF, find where get_session_state is defined